# FOL formula and check valididty of this?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I think the following is logically valid, but my TA says it's not logically valid.

$ \forall x (A(x) \to B(x)) \to ( \exists x A(x) \vee \exists x B(x)) $

Who Can Clarify me about this Formula ?

Comment: Imagine a structure where $\neg Ac$ and $\neg Bc$.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is *false* in the structure whose carrier set is $\{42\}$ and the interpretation of $A$ and $B$ are both $\varnothing$.

Since there is a structure where the formula is false, it is not logically valid.

---

If you looks at the possible models of your formula, with interpretaions $\hat A$, $\hat B$ of the predicates $A$ and $B$, the part $\forall x(A(x)\to B(x))$ says that $\hat A\subseteq \hat B$. And $\exists x A(x)\lor \exists x B(x)$ says that eat least one of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ is non-empty.

However just because $\hat A$ is a subset of $\hat B$ doesn't mean the sets can't be empty.